What powers do federal universities have in Brazil to deny promotion to a permanent university professor?
Introduction.  In Brazil, federal university professors hold permanent positions with the university, a position obtained by a public competition and it might be more or less equivalent to the tenure in the United States.  So, for example, firing a professor for non-major reasons such as low performance is simply unseen.
Question.  However, the career of every civil servant goes through timely promotions.  These promotions are approved by commissions formed with the usual objective of making sure that bureaucratic properties of the professor's career is all in order.  Could a department or an institute add requirements to concede or uphold a promotion?  For instance, could a department legally oblige professors to publish a certain number of papers (or anything of that sort) in order to get the next promotion?
Intention.  I'm interested in learning more about how much power does a federal university have over a civil servant's career of a federal university professor in Brazil.  If both sides conflict for whatever reason, what sort of limits or guarantees does the law present to either side?
Scope.  To make the question a bit easier, I'm restrict myself to the federal legislation; that is, federal universities only.  If I can find my way in the federal law, I should be able to continue my search on my own.
Discussion.  It is a constitutional guarantee that universities in Brazil have administrative autonomy, which is stated by article 207 of the federal constitution of 1988:

as universidades gozam de autonomia didático-científica,
administrativa e de gestão financeira e patrimonial, e obedecerão ao
princípio de indissociabilidade entre ensino, pesquisa e extensão.
-- Article 207, Federal Constitution, 1988.

So I'm thinking that in that way the university could set some requirements regarding promotions of employees in general and that would apply to professors as well.  But it's not clear that a department, an institute or a college would have such power.
I'm not aware of any article in any law that might protect the university professor against a possible consensus reached by the institution (by the institute, by the department to which the professor belongs) which might not work in favor of a professor.  If you can point out any relevant law in that direction, I might be able to take it from there.

I'm having a hard to understanding why you would think that there is any circumstance under which the university would have to promote someone that the appropriate board or commission didn't want to promote.

Okay, let me try to rethink the question completely.  Can a department approve rules for promotions such as having published N papers up to the promotion?  That's just an example.  I'm interested in what authority does a department have to define criteria for promotion.  I don't think the law says anything about that at all, so it seems to me that the department is able to approve criteria and enforce it through the commissions.

What made you ask the question? In general, of course people who handle promotions can decide who to promote and who not to promote unless there is a reason otherwise. Is there anything that made you think otherwise?

It's not clear to me that a person would not be promoted even if the commission doesn't recommend.  There's nothing in the law that seems to say that the commission must approve or that the department must approve.  I'm trying to understand how the law interferes or does not interfere in this process.  That's what made me ask the question.

The main Brazilian law that is concerned with federal employees is the Law 8112 from 1990.  In article 10, we have "[...] Parágrafo único. Os demais requisitos para o ingresso e o desenvolvimento do servidor na carreira, mediante promoção, ascensão e acesso, serão estabelecidos pela lei que fixar as diretrizes do sistema de carreira na Administração Pública Federal e seus regulamentos."  This is saying that promotions will be regulated by some law and I don't know if this law was ever published---which is not uncommon.

@ohwilleke the universities this question refers to are Brazilian federal (hence public) ones. Professors in there are public servants and general rules to public servants apply to them. On the other hand, federal universities in Brazil are not regular public entities: they have a greater level of autonomy granted by the Constitution. So this question wants to know if that autonomy is enough to override the general rules related to professor careers. It's seems to be a perfectly valid question for this site.
